# How to inject tag in single html page with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-boot

We are using OAuth authorization and our internal JWT tokens with spring boot(stateless backend) + React. After several redicrections for getting user info we create jwt-token. And we need somehow to send it to client with html page. We can use

1. Request params (is not big enought for our token)
2. Cookie (is big enought for our token)
3. Put token into html page

So, 1 and 2 aren't our choice. We decided to put token into html page before sending to client. On client side just read it with js.

My question is: how to dynamically change html content before sending it to customer with spring boot?

Are there other methods solving this problem for stateless backend?

Comment: Why html? Just save token in localStorage. What is problem?

Comment: User click on login button, after that he is being redirected to authorization site, after that this site redirect user to our backend. Before return him html i also need to give him token.

Comment: Hmm. Good questiom, i'm also interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved my issue in next way

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String processLogin(HttpServletResponse response,
                           @RequestParam(value = "code") String code)throws IOException {

    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    Resource file = new ClassPathResource("/META-INF/resources/index.html");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream(), UTF_8));
    htmlSourceContent = bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());


    //do changes with htmlSourceContent
    response.getOutputStream().write(htmlSourceContent);
    log.debug("Authentication successfully passed");
 }
```